# Check checkbox value only once inside a nested loop

Tags: excel, vba, nested

I am checking the value of a checkbox on my userform inside a nested loop. I want to know if there is a way to do this before the loops because basically the code is running the same check over and over again...

what it is doing is it loops through the entire column B and combines all the rows that have the same conditions. then it puts in into an array and prints. So I need to do this checkbox check twice. Any help is appreciated!

```
Dim dict As Object
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim aCell As Range
Dim ArrayLen As Long
Dim LArr() As Single
Dim MPch As Boolean

MPch = UserForm1.MPCheck1.Value
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        X = 0
        
  With wks
  
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
        ReDim LArr(LastRow)

        For Each aCell In .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
            
                If MPch = True Then
                    UniqueCombo = aCell.Value & "," & aCell.Offset(0, 1) & aCell.Offset(0, 2)
                Else
                    UniqueCombo = aCell.Value & "," & aCell.Offset(0, 1) & aCell.Offset(0, 2) & "," & aCell.Offset(0, 5)
                End If
            
            DieCoordinate = aCell.Value & "," & aCell.Offset(0, 1)
            SheetName = aCell.Offset(0, 2) & "-" & aCell.Offset(0, 5)
        
                If Not dict.exists(UniqueCombo) Then
                    VarLastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).row + 1
                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(VarLastRow, 5) = DieCoordinate
                    dict(UniqueCombo) = True 'add this value
                                           
                    For o = 2 To LastRow
                        
                        If MPch = True Then
                            VariableCombo = .Cells(o, 2) & "," & .Cells(o, 3) & .Cells(o, 4)
                        Else
                            VariableCombo = .Cells(o, 2) & "," & .Cells(o, 3) & .Cells(o, 4) & "," & .Cells(o, 7)
                        End If
                    
                        VariableCombo = .Cells(o, 2) & "," & .Cells(o, 3) & .Cells(o, 4) & "," & .Cells(o, 7)

                            If UniqueCombo = VariableCombo And .Cells(o, 6).Interior.ColorIndex = -4142 And _
                            .Cells(o, 6) <> "*" And .Cells(o, 6) <> "0" And .Cells(o, 6) <> "" Then

                                CDTot = CDTot + .Cells(o, 6)
                                LArr(X) = .Cells(o, 6)
                                X = X + 1
      
                            End If
    
                    Next
      
                        If X = 0 Then
                            ArrayLen = 0
                            Else
                            ReDim Preserve LArr(UBound(LArr) - (LastRow - X + 1))
                            ArrayLen = UBound(LArr) - LBound(LArr) + 1
                        End If
          
                        If ArrayLen < UserForm1.TextBox7 Then
                         ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Range(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(VarLastRow, 5), ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(VarLastRow, 10)).Interior.ColorIndex = 53
                        End If
     
                        LCDUCD = 3 * Application.WorksheetFunction.StDev_P(LArr)
                        DieAver = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(LArr)
        
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(VarLastRow, 7) = LCDUCD
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(VarLastRow, 6) = DieAver
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(VarLastRow, 8) = aCell.Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(VarLastRow, 9) = aCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(SheetName).Cells(VarLastRow, 10) = ArrayLen
                       
                
                End If
                
                ReDim LArr(LastRow)
                X = 0
        Next aCell
```

End With

Comment: Dim a Boolean variable and assign it the value of the checkbox before you start looping.

Comment: `Dim bMP as Boolean`

Comment: `bMP  = UserForm1.MPCheck1.Value1`

Comment: Then use `bMP` in your loop instead of `UserForm1.MPCheck1.Value1`

Comment: Ah ok, but it`s not possible to do the entire check before the loop? I guess storing the checkbox value inside a Boolean will speed up the process a little bit since is does not need to look at the userform each time?

Comment: If you are trying to speed up the execution time of your code, you could also bring ALL of the cell values over to VBA in the form of a Variant array all at once and then interrogate the array instead of all the individual cell references. This will be MUCH faster.

Comment: Yes. But why is it not possible to do it before the loop?

Comment: Because I have 2 conditions in each loop that need to be done. To put it in words. If checkbox value is true then it needs to compare column B+C+D with another column B+C+D. If the value is false it needs to compare B+C+D+G.

Comment: You need to branch your code based on the condition, so you need something to use for that decision. A Boolean will be faster than interrogating a control on a user form. But there will be a massive increase in speed if you follow my advice on the Variant array. It will literally by thousands of times faster. And you can also pick up some speed by NOT `ReDim Preserve LArr()` on every iteration. Make that array as large as it could possibly need to be for your scenario before you start and then ReDim it ONCE at the very end.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will add the Boolean, for the array I will look into it, this was my first case working with arrays. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: You are welcome. When you have nested loops, it will pay off tremendously to optimize the inner loops to the bare minimum of processing. ReDims are slow. ReDim with Presever is even much slower. And every time you reference a worksheet range or function it is terribly slow. Don't ever do these things in an inner loop!

Comment: Great, after changing the ReDims as you suggested I can now run my macro multiple times without it going slower each time it runs!

Comment: Yeah, the ReDim Preserve was churning heap memory ferociously. Still, a much larger speedup will be realized when you implement my Variant array suggestion.

Comment: Do you have a link with some explanation for this? When I change my array to a variant, I get an error on a workwheetfunction that I call on the array. I'm using tha `average` and `stdev_p` funtions on my array. See my code above which I edited after your suggestion without the ReDim Preserve

Comment: That's the wrong array. Your existing array is fine now that you are not ReDimming it continuously. You do not need to change that array into a Variant. My suggestion in comment #5 was to bring all of the worksheet data into VBA in one shot... into another array... a Variant array... and then loop through that instead of individual cells in the worksheet. For example, `v = [A1:Z999]` and then you have a copy of the data in that range stored in `v()` with 999 rows and 26 columns. This ONE interaction with that worksheet will be quick... maybe 10 milliseconds. But interrogating `v()` is fast.

Comment: Obviously `v = [A1:Z999]` is just an example. Use whatever range is required for your scenario. With `A1:Z999` as the source, it is easy to translate cell coordinates to the array coordinates. For example, `v(3, 10)` has a copy of the data that was in cell `C10`.